# Wordpress Template Creation from HTML

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a HTML template which uses various div structure. Now I have to create this into a wordpress theme. I am a bit confused with this. I am attaching the design here[image]

So all the pink borders are divs. Now Do I put the whole content in the wordpress page, or is there a better way of creating the template? I was hoping that I just put the contents in the ADD PAGE area. and it would automatically take the alignment. All the black lines are contents(text). This is the design of a single page. Any idea of how make the template so that the contents are aligned automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the image together with the 3 divs next to it all belong to one subject?
If so you could use a custom post type and then adding different meta boxes for those different divs. Another solution would be using shortcodes like so `[divone][/divone]` `[divtwo][/divtwo]` you can create those with the following code:

```
function divone_func($atts, $content="") {
     return '<div class="one">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('divone', 'divone_func');
```

This code goes into your `functions.php` file, in your `style.css` you can style the div with the following code:

```
div.one{
    /* your CSS here */
}
```

**More reading:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: I am not trying to use plugin. Rather this is a page design in HTML and I want this design to be converted to wordpress. So my question is as they are different divs , how to insert only text between them when I am creating a new page.

Comment: The code above doesn't require you to use a plugin, it goes into your `functions.php` file. I've edited the post

Comment: @Roger Is that the answer you were looking for? If so please accept it. :)